# Convert set of Coordinates into a sorted 2D Array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array, coordinates

Suppose I have a set of n coordinates (x, y) e.g.
(123, 41), (123, 50), (555, 10), (600, 10)

And I wanted to convert it into a 2D array where:

- The amount of columns is equal to the unique number of x coordinates
- The amount of rows is equal to the unique number of y coordinates
- No two set of coordinates will be exactly the same and there are no constraints on what the values of x and y can be.
- A coordinate is placed at indices relative to the x and y of all other coordinates. E.g. (555,10) has the second greatest x coordinate (x=1) and one of the smallest y coordinates (y=0) so its position will be [1][0]

  |  | x=0 | x=1 | x=2 |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | y=0 | null | (555, 10) | (600, 10) |
  | y=1 | (123, 41) | null | null |
  | y=2 | (123, 50) | null | null |

*(There are 3 unique x coordinates (123, 555, 666) and 3 unique y coordinates (41, 50, 10) so array is 3x3)*

What algorithm can I use to generate a 2D array from a set of coordinates as described above? I've attempted to create my own but it is very slow when n is very large O(n^2).

Comment: *Please mention the constraints of the problem.* How many number of points can be given at maximum? If `(x, y)` is any valid coordinate, how big `x` or `y` can be? Will `x` and `y` always be less then `n` where n is the number of points to be inputted?

Comment: You should state the range of `n` as in 1 <= `n` <= 1000.  Also will `x` be less than `n` like  1 <= `x` <= `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

1. Get all distinct `x` and `y` coordinates and sort them.
2. For each point, get the position of it's `x` and `y` coordinate in the respective sorted arrays. Place the point in this position in the result array.

Something like this (in Python):

```py
# cook your dish here
points = [(123, 41), (123, 50), (555, 10), (600, 10)]
x_coords = sorted(list(set(i[0] for i in points))) # all distinct x coordinates
y_coords = sorted(list(set(i[1] for i in points))) # all distinct y coordinates
result = [[0 for i in range(len(x_coords))] for j in range(len(y_coords))]

for i in points:
    x_final = x_coords.index(i[0])
    y_final = y_coords.index(i[1])
    result[y_final][x_final] = i
    
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

This gives:

```
[0, (555, 10), (600, 10)]
[(123, 41), 0, 0]
[(123, 50), 0, 0]
```

1. You can replace the zeros with `None` or `null` as per your convenience.
2. This method has `O(NlogN)` time complexity.

**Edit**: `index()` method might not be the most efficient way depending on the language/data structure used. You can use binary search to implement the same.

Comment: To provide O(NlogN), one should use binary search rather than x_coords.index

Comment: @MBo yes, I know. Added it to the answer as well